# Wireless Repeater with DD-WRT

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, repeater

I have an ATT wireless modem and a LinkSys Router with DD-WRT v24 sp1 installed. I went through the instructions on this [page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wlan_Repeater) and got to the point that the DD-WRT router can talk with the modem. My goal is to use the LinkSys as a wireless repeater, but for now, while I'm testing, I'm connecting to the LinkSys router via wire.

From the DD-WRT interface, if I go to Administration -> Commands and run a "ping google.com" I get a reply, so that tells me the LinkSys and the modem are talking. However, if I try to ping google from the computer, while connected to DD-WRT via wire, I get time-outs.

I followed all the recommendations / steps on the [WLAN repeater](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wlan_Repeater) page. Any idea what else I could try? Thank you!

EDIT:

The configuration is something like this:

```
ATT modem:
  default gateway: 192.168.1.254
|
(wireless connection)
|
LinkSys WRT54GL v1.1 with DD-WRT v24 sp1
|
(wired connection)
[my computer]
  IP: 192.168.2.128
  default gateway: 192.168.2.1 (LinkSys's IP)
```

Comment: Just to verify, when you ping google.com does it actually reach an external IP?

Comment: Also check if the wired computer receives a correct DHCP assigned IP.

Comment: 1) If I ping from the computer that's connected to DD-WRT router all the pings time out. Not sure what you mean with "reach an external IP." If I don't get a reply from ping I guess it doesn't, right? If I ping from DD-WRT interface it works (ping, i.e.)
2) The wireless router is on a 192.168.1.x subnet, I assigned a 192.168.2.x subnet for the DD-WRT router. When connected to DD-WRT I get a correct (I say) 192.168.2.108 (usually) IP.
Thanks.

Comment: check MAC filtering settings and make sure your NIC's MAC is in the allow list.

Comment: @John: I didn't see any MAC filtering options on DD-WRT that would be configured. Is there a specific place you're thinking about?

Comment: @pbz, sounds like DD-WRT isn't routing packets between the two subnets.  Could you try putting it on Repeater Bridge, save, apply, reboot and see if that works?

Comment: @hyperslug: Simply changing it to repeater bridge worked! Now I'm getting an IP from the 192.168.1.x subnet (not 192.168.1.x). Now if I can connect to it wirelessly I'd be all set. Thank you!!!

Comment: @pbz, hm shot in the dark, but good to hear it worked.

Comment: Above: I meant "not 192.168.2.x"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pbz found that configuring DD-WRT as a [Repeater Bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge) instead of Repeater allowed him to access the internet when connected to his DD-WRT device via ethernet cable.

```
Wireless -> Basic Settings -> Wireless Mode -> Repeater Bridge
```

In contrast to Repeater, Repeater Bridge allows for connecting clients to be on the same subnet, in his case `192.168.1.x`.  Here is a comparison matrix between [WDS vs Repeater vs Repeater Bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeating_Mode_Comparisons#WDS_vs_R_.28Repeater.29_vs_RB_.28Repeater_Bridge.29) features.

Comment: One interesting problem, is that after switching to RB mode, even when connected via wire, the gateway became the ATT modem. The bridge became invisible as it's replicating the original router -- at least that's my understanding. So... how can I access the DD-WRT now? :) And is there a way to know, when connecting wirelessly, that I'm connecting to the ATT modem or the DD-WRT router? It works, I'm not complaining, just trying to understand. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: Yeah? You sure the DD-WRT/Linksys doesn't get an IP?  Do you have an IP scanning tool, like Angry IP Scanner http://www.angryziber.com/ipscan/ipscan.exe to see if you can find it?

Answer (score 0):

i know its late to answer this post but incase someone else reads it later ill post
to get access to the ddwrt just change the ip on either the dd-wrt seperate from the original group range ie. router is 192.168.0.1 ddwrt is 192.168.1.1 or pull up your original router and see what clients are connected and find the ip given for the ddwrt  =D